# React Typescript: can't set State

Tags: javascript, reactjs, typescript, state

I have an array that contains a string. I'm trying to take that string and join it with another string. When I `console.log('Dates: ' + mergedActions)` I get back both strings together. However when I `console.log('Dates: ' + this.state.MergedAllActions)` it's empty. I tried adding a timeout to the console log but still nothing.

Any idea why `mergedActions` even though it contains information doesn't get set in `MergedAllActions`?

```
let currentAction = 'Form has been submitted';
let mergedActions = this.state.Product[0].AllActions + ',' + currentAction;
this.setState({ MergedAllActions: mergedActions });
console.log('Dates: ' + mergedActions);  
console.log('Dates: ' + this.state.MergedAllActions);
```

Console below:

```
Dates: first Step,First Approver accepted
Dates:
```

Answer (score 1):

setState is asynchronous, but it supports a callback as the 2nd argument.
Change to

```
this.setState({ MergedAllActions: mergedActions }, console.log(this.state.MergedAllActions));
```

Answer (score 1):

[`setState` is asynchronous](https://reactjs.org/docs/react-component.html#setstate), as the documentation explains:

> setState() enqueues changes to the component state [...]
> Think of setState() as a request rather than an immediate command to update the component. [...]
> setState() does not always immediately update the component. [...] **This makes reading this.state right after calling setState() a potential pitfall.**
> **Instead, use `componentDidUpdate` or a setState callback (`setState(updater, callback)`), either of which are guaranteed to fire after the update has been applied.**

(Emphasis mine.)

Comment: Hi thanks for the reply, I'm still new to react. So I'm doing this in a `submit` function. On submit I'm doing this calculations then pushing the new set state to my `array` any ideas?

Comment: As the doc fragment above explains, the change to your state is not immediately available after you call `setState()`, since `setState()` is asynchronous. It will be reflected in state when the component is re-rendered the next time.